# Frame without borders and default controls. Sizers doesn't work

Tags: wxwidgets

I try to write small GUI programm for windows using wx and wxFrame. I have this code in ctor:

```
MainFrame::MainFrame(wxPoint pos)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, wxT("Sample text"), pos,
              wxDefaultSize, wxBORDER_NONE | wxFRAME_NOTASKBAR)
{
    SetSize(wxSize(250, 100));
    CreateLayout();
}
```

And **CreateLayout** function:

```
void MainFrame::CreateLayout()
{
    wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    sizer->Add(new wxStaticText(this, -1, "1000.56"), 0, wxLEFT|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);

    SetSizer(sizer);
}
```

As you can see, I want to align text to vertical center of the frame. But with this set of frame style flags sizers doesn't work! They work only if i set ***wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE***! But i need to have frame without borders and capture and close|minimize|maximize buttons, how can I get this work?

Comment: This is supposed to work, of course. Hard to say what goes wrong without knowing more about your platform and about what exactly does "doesn't work" mean. Have you tried modifying the minimal sample to do this?

Comment: I need to be StaticText vertically centered and 5px padding from the left side of frame. Simply enough? Yea, but when i remove borders from frame, Static text aligned to the top-left corner, sizers and borders and align totally ignored. How to make frame without borders with working sizers?

Comment: @VZ. I've added some information to my answer that may help you figure out why this happens, and whether it's a bug or a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `MainFrame` constructor, move the call to `SetSize()` **after** the call to `CreateLayout()`. That's it.

---

Normally, the call to `Show()` after creating the frame should make the above unnecessary, but it looks like in this case it doesn't (see the details below). Anyway, I think it makes sense to first set up all the sizers and controls inside the window, and then change the size to trigger a `Layout()`, just to be on the safe side.

This also means an alternative solution is to leave the call to `SetSize()` where it is, and force a layout by adding a call to `Layout()` at the very end of your `CreateLayout()`. But... I like being *efficient* (read: *lazy*); I'd go with the first solution.

---

EDIT: I've found some information regarding why this happens.

For a `wxFrame` created with `wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE`, the call to `Show()` ends up calling `::ShowWindow()`, which triggers a `WM_SIZE`, which eventually triggers a `Layout()`.

For a `wxFrame` created with `wxBORDER_NONE`, `::ShowWindow()` doesn't seem to trigger a `WM_SIZE`, which is why the solutions above for forcing the call to `Layout()` are necessary.

Comment: Interesting, the fact that `Show()` doesn't result in a `wxEVT_SIZE` when `wxBORDER_NONE` is used is arguably a bug in wxMSW.

Comment: @VZ. Or Windows' `::ShowWindow()` is to blame, but a workaround in wx would be very useful nonetheless.